# How to compile apache httpd with visual studio 2013 comunity edition?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Please if someone could tell me a good guide on how to compile the apache server in visual studio 2013. What happens is when I open the downloaded project file, it asks me to modify some files and when I try to do so I get a bunch of error massages.

As I understand the source files downloaded from the apache servers is for unix systems and I read somewhere that the files need to be modified in order to be compiled for windows. Now another question here is, why would you need to modify the source code for windows shouldn't the compilers do this while compiling and output a file that runs on windows regardless of what functions are called in the source file?

As you can tell I am kind of confused with this hole thing, I don't think its a complicated matted, just needs some explaining, thanks.